# I want to abbreviate a string with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a table and I want to change a column.  The column contains a string.

For example: "this is my string" --> "this is my...".

I tried to do this with `abbreviate()`.

```
<td th:text="${#strings.abbreviate( ${fgp.explanation}, 10)}"></td>
```

But I receive this error : `EL1043E: Unexpected token. Expected 'rparen())' but
was 'lcurly({)'.
S{fgp.explanation} contains the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax needs to be corrected.

The general case is: `${#strings.abbreviate(str,10)}`  so you would want:

`<td th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(fgp.explanation, 10)}">this is my...</td>`

Comment: Great!  I feel like in these cases, the error message could be improved.