# Using word-wrap: break-word in flyingsaucer

Tags: java

The css style "word-wrap: break-word" does not work while I export the html file to PDF by flyingsaucer.

I defined a class in css file

```
.class-name{
  word-wrap: break-word
}
```

and below is my html file

```
<table class="class-name">
<tr>
  <td>
    something very long
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I followed the solution in
[number cannot be wrapped in flyingsaucer and itext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37392644/number-cannot-be-wrapped-in-flyingsaucer-and-itext) but it did not work.

The version of my flyingsaucer is >9 and the version of itext is 2.1.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also have similar experience. The version of my flying saucer was 9.0.4 and the version of iText was also 2.1.7 .

At first, I was disappointed because I found that ["word-wrap" is a CSS 3.0 feature](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) but flying saucer 9.0.4 officially supports up to CSS 2.1 .

However, I find that "word-wrap" still works while I write inline style in HTML file instead of using separate CSS file. You can try the following code to export PDF again.

```
<table style="word-wrap: break-word">
<tr>
  <td>
    something very long
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! I struggled with that a while, but this resolves my case completely. Thanks!